# Authorize attribute for any roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, authorization

Let's say I have WebApi Controller

```
[Authorize]
public class SomeApiController : ApiController
```

Controller action methods itself does not have any `[Authorize]` or `[AllowAnonymous]` attributes.

I want Authorize attribute to return 401 (Unauthorized) error if user has no roles - seems logical (if user had role and now doesn't have ANY - he shouldn't be allowed to perform action even though user is authenticated). I have looked to asp.net mvc webstack I have found the following code in Authorize attribute:

```
if (_rolesSplit.Length > 0 && !_rolesSplit.Any(user.IsInRole))
{
    return false;
}
```

So looks like if we didn't passed roles authorize attribute just checks if user is authenticated. Setting each role in Roles list is not an option for me ( I mean `[Authorize(Roles="role1,role2,...")]`).

Therefore question - can I somehow achieve setting Authorize attribute to check if user has ANY role. Or it's better to write custom attribute inherited from above?

Answer (score 0):

Create custom attribute like below:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    string[] userRoles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);

    if (!userRoles.Any())
    {
        throw new HttpException(401, "Unauthorized");
    }
    base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
}
```

}

Hope it helps

Comment: I know how to create custom attribute. Question is there any common sense solution without implementing custom attribute. Also your attribute doesn't suite my need - i want to check if user has ANY role. So i need inject role provider in that case... But that's another topic

Comment: I can't see any common sense solution without implementing custom attribute for your case, but if there is a solution I would be glad to see it. If the source code I provided doesn't suite your need, sorry, but it's just give you some idea of how to solve your problem.
I updated it again, hope this time it can give you a better idea in solving the problem.

Comment: Why are you calling base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filtercontext); ?  You should call base.OnAuthorization(filtercontext);